# How to create a new Visual Studio project to use Affdex SDK

Tags: affdex-sdk

I need to use Affdex SDK in a research project, but I am having problems starting the project with C#.

In Visual Studio I did the following steps:

1. I created a new project;
2. I added a reference to Affdex.dll.

However, when I try to instantiate a `CameraDetector` object, I have an exception with the message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

I know that my Affdex SDK is functional because I downloaded the sample project and it works perfectly. Furthermore, I used this project as base, I removed all sample classes, and I added my own classes and the project works appropriately. My conclusion is that I have to include another reference or configuration to the new project.

So, I would to know how is the step-by-step to create a new Visual Studio project to use the Affdex SDK.

Answer (score 3):

This exception occurs since you did not reference the affdex-native.dll in your Visual Studio project. **The .NET assembly depends on the affdex-native.dll and loads it in runtime**. You can copy the affdex-native.dll as a reference to the output directory.

You can refer to the developer portal for [using the C# SDK](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_1/windows/#using-the-sdk). We have a quick start guide for [analyzing the camera feed](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_1/windows/analyze-camera/).We have a couple of sample apps like [AffdexMe](https://github.com/Affectiva/affdexme-win) and [csharp-sample-apps](https://github.com/Affectiva/csharp-sample-apps) which you can take a look at on [github](https://github.com/Affectiva) for quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have referenced the correct dll. Usually, BadImage means that you have referenced the x64 dll to a x86 project. Make sure that your Platform, and the architecture of referenced dll, are same.

Best regards,
Silviu.